# Incorporate webpack input filepath in output file path

Tags: webpack

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
js
- account
  - login.js
  - register.js
- product
  - index.js
```

What I want to do is make different webpacks for each file, but use the same folder structure:

```
dist
- account
  - login.bundle.js
  - register.bundle.js
- product
  - index.bundle.js
```

Here is what I imagine the `webpack.config.js` file would look like:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        account-login: "./js/account/login.js",
        account-register: "./js/account/register.js",
        product-index: "./js/product/index.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: "./dist",
        filename: "[???]/[???].bundle.js"
    }
};
```

Is this something that could be done? I know there's a `[name]` placeholder, but I think I also need a path placeholder, which I couldn't find.

Comment: That works for entry points, but it does not work for output files... the outputs are all going to the same place. You would need to copy them over to the desired locaiton or create different webpack configs

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case. :( But thank you, that was helpful.